# Android add map address to a webview (iframe)

Tags: android, webview

```
                    String s="..<td colspan=2 style='border-bottom: solid 1px #efefef; width:100%'>" +
                    "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"150\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border: solid 1px #dedede; padding:2px;\" scrolling=\"no\" " +
                    "src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=hu&geocode=&" +
                    "q="+address+"&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear="+address+"&z=14&output=embed\"></iframe>"+
                    "</td>" +
                    "</tr>...";

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL (null, s, "text/html", "utf-8",   "about:blank");
```

and then its not working... showing up a "loading" and login window. why? in a normal browser this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here: First off, Javascript is disabled in WebViews if you don't explicitly enable it. See WebSettings' [`setJavascriptEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29) method. Also, loadDataWithBaseUrl uses the first argument to determine a bunch of security behaviors (see [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) on that method), including I believe blocking scripts from fetching external resources if the base URL is null or starts with "data://". Try using any URL with "http://" at the beginning for the first argument and see if that helps, and of course make sure you have the `INTERNET` permission in your app's manifest.

But before all that... why don't you just use a [MapView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)? IFraming a javascript Google Maps URL seems silly when you can just use a native map control.

Comment: i know the mapview, but i need this in this case, thank u! setJavascriptEnabled solved my probleme.